# I want my x folder with the y.png files to take the name of z.png

Tags: python

you will find my code i am not python pro but i do everything to become it

```
import os, sys
os.listdir(os.getcwd())


Out[3]: ['.ipynb_checkpoints',
         'helmet_10_0.png',
         'helmet_10_1.png',
         'helmet_10_10.png',

I wish

Out[0]: ['casque_Chantier_10_0.png',
         'casque_Chantier_10_10.png',
         'casque_Chantier_10_100.png'
```

so on

```
source = 'D:\\Chasse_Au_tressor\\base_agmt\\extractedFrames_step_5\\helmet_10_0.png'


dest = 'D:\\Chasse_Au_tressor\\base_agmt\\extractedFrames_step_5\\Casque_Chantier_10_0.png'

os.rename(source, dest)
Out[2]: ['casque_Chantier_10_0.png',
         'helmet_10_1.png',
         'helmet_10_10.png',
         'helmet_10_100.png',
         'helmet_10_101.png',
```

I can't make a loop which takes all the files with 'glob' and renames them

```
<ipython-input-33-1a271eebe4a0> in <module>
      1 for i in source:
      2     if i != dest:
----> 3         os.rename(i,dest)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'D' -> 'D:\\Chasse_Au_tressor\\base_agmt\\extractedFrames_step_5\\Casque_Chantier_{*}.png'
```

I want the images on casque_Chantier_{index=1}.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can just rename the file name instead of opening it and renaming it once again which will save memory while performing the action on multiple files in a for loop. This will also make sure that only the intended files i.e. file names which start with "helmet" alone are renamed

```
#Import package
import os

#Loop through the file names
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.startswith("helmet_"):
        os.rename(filename, "casque_Chantier_"+filename[7:])
```

Cheers!

Comment: thank you very much real i become even more fan of python

Answer (score 0):

The following code iterates through each file and renames the file as required. It replaces the "helmet_" part with "casque_Chantier_". 
I have set this up so that it runs in the same folder as the files to be renamed.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir():
    os.rename(file, file.replace("helmet_","casque_Chantier_")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys

directory = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(directory)

renamed_filenames = [f.replace('helmet', 'casque_Chantier') for f in filenames]

for i in range(len(filenames)):

    source_filepath = os.path.join(directory, filenames[i])
    dest_filepath = os.path.join(directory, renamed_filenames[i])

    os.rename(source_filepath, dest_filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for python 3.6

You will need replace from string library to change 'helmet' into 'casque_Chantier' :

```
import shutil
import os
dir_path = os.getcwd()

for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    src = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
    dst = os.path.join(dir_path, filename.replace("helmet", "casque_Chantier"))
    shutil.move(src, dst)
```